# image not displaying nicely in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to display this image in a fullscreen window in pygame as the texture for my floor[image]

but when i try to actually display the image inside the pygame window, it comes up as this[image]
for some reason there are random blobs of blue coming up in the image. i used this code to try and put in my image

```
width,height=pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
floorimg=pygame.image.load("assets//image.png")
win.blit(floorimg,(0,height-100))
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is not the code but the image itself...

[Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNnCt.png) is the link of the "floor" image with the transparent area colored using Windows Paint3D.

The code works perfectly fine, but you might need to get some clean pictures in the future.

Comment: i think i fixed it by using an image compressor to take the image colors to 10, turns out photoshop is way too good at this and made a bunch of invisible colors, which the compressor removed later on.

Comment: @pert also just to be sure, to always check the image (especially PNG) after every compress. Image compression programs almost always mess up transparent PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

I saved your image and wrote this script to draw it:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((1300, 200), 0 , 32)
width,height=pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()
floorimg = pygame.image.load("floor.png")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    window.fill((0))
    window.blit(floorimg,(0,height-100))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

It seems to have similar problem to yours if the image is converted to pygame format(which I am assuming you do somewhere else in your code?)

```
floorimg = pygame.image.load("floor.png").convert()
```

[image]

But this can easily be solved by taking transparency into account while converting, which is done by `convert_alpha`.

```
floorimg = pygame.image.load("floor.png").convert_alpha()
```

This results in an image similar to the first one.

Comment: 1.) "which I am assuming you do ..." - No, this is not the problem here. I know the problem well. Your image is different from that one in the question. The problem is related to the pygame blending function and can be solved using different special_flags in [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). 2.) *"the image is converted to pygame format"* - a "pygame format" does not exist. There are formats with and without an alpha channel, but that's nothing special about pygame.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ahh sorry If I was wrong. I thought pygame had it's own sprite format. I think I keep confusing stuff from this other graphics library that I am learning with pygame.